# htaccess redirect if not include in group IP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I'm new in htaccess. I have problem with htaccess redirect if the IPs are not from my group IP. My group IP always have 106.161.xxx.xxx. The 106.161 always same. But I have to redirect if IP is not come from 106.161. I use basic htaccess from Codeigniter which has.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and now I modify with,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^106.161\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/notmygroup [L]
```

I don't find a way yet. If there any basic tutorial or suggestion about htaccess are welcome.
Thanks you.

Comment: First: you have a typo in your rules, check the IP address...

Comment: Second: you should code the redirection to example.com/notmygroup as a result of the negation of your condition.

Comment: Thirs: the documentation of apaches rewriting module is of _excellent_ quality and comes with great examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I have updated my question.

Comment: Hm, can't really spot much difference...